# ArgoCD overriding helm releaseName gives an error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd, argo

ArgoCD complaining about overriding helm release name, see the error below:

```
level=fatal msg="rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = application spec for my-app-suffix is invalid: InvalidSpecError: Unable to generate manifests 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = `helm template . --name-template my-app --namespace  .... failed exit status 1: Error: cannot set --name-template and also specify a name"
```

The releaseName was specified on the app to be `my-app` so that the application name `my-app-suffix` does not equal the helm release name...

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-app-suffix
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  project: my-project
  destination:
    server: serverUrl
    namespace: my-namespace
  source:
    repoURL: repoUrl
    targetRevision: targetRevision
    path: ./k8s/helm/my-app
    helm:
      releaseName: my-app
      parameters:
      - name: image.repo
        value: xxxx
      - name: image.tag
        value: xxx
      valueFiles:
      - ../values.my-app.yaml
```

This error appeared out of nowhere after I added `helm parameters`...